# Is Path.replace equivalent to os.replace or shutil.move?

Tags: python, file-rename, pathlib

The documentation of the [`pathlib.Path.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace) method states:

> Rename this file or directory to the given target. If target points to
>   an existing file or directory, it will be unconditionally replaced.

This lacks a bit of detail. For comparison, here's the documentation of [`os.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace):

> Rename the file or directory `src` to `dst`. If `dst` is a directory,
>   `OSError` will be raised. If `dst` exists and is a file, it will be
>   replaced silently if the user has permission. The operation may fail
>   if `src` and `dst` are on different filesystems. If successful, the
>   renaming will be an atomic operation (this is a POSIX requirement).

The important part being *"The operation may fail if `src` and `dst` are on different filesystems"*. Unlike `os.replace`, [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) does not have this problem:

> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then `os.rename()` is
>   used. Otherwise, `src` is copied to `dst` using `copy_function` and then
>   removed.

So, which of these functions is `Path.replace` using? Is there any risk of `Path.replace` failing because the destination is on a different file system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Path(x).replace(y)` just calls `os.replace(x, y)`. You can see this in [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a7987e71939fa631296f83861fb376361ddd59ee/Lib/pathlib.py#L418):

```
class _NormalAccessor(_Accessor):
    # [...]
    replace = os.replace
    # [...]

_normal_accessor = _NormalAccessor()

# [...]

class Path(PurePath):
    # [...]
    def _init(self,
              # Private non-constructor arguments
              template=None,
              ):
        self._closed = False
        if template is not None:
            self._accessor = template._accessor
        else:
            self._accessor = _normal_accessor

    # [...]

    def replace(self, target):
        """
        Rename this path to the given path, clobbering the existing
        destination if it exists.
        """
        if self._closed:
            self._raise_closed()
        self._accessor.replace(self, target)
```